# Mac OS X - associate application with file type icon

Tags: macos

I want to make it that for a certain file type, the icon is dynamically generated by my app. For example, photos appear as thumbnails in the Finder - I want .myapp files to appear as special, per-file generated icons in the Finder. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Review apple documentation for CFBundleTypeName, CFBundleTypeIconFile, LSItemContentTypes, etc...
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html

Comment: Links make poor answers. For example, that link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same. The solution I found useful was to register your own file type for the application. To do that you need to specify new key in info.plist of your application. Specify `CFBundleTypeName`(your file type) and `CFBundleTypeExtensions`(your file extension like `mytxt`). To specify custom icons fill the `CFBundleTypeIconFile` with your `.icns` file name. It is also important to put the `.icns` file inside `Resources` in your `.app`.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>your_file_type</string>

        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>your_file_type</string>
        </array>

        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>app.icns</string>

        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>

        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <false />

        <key>NSPersistentStoreTypeKey</key>
        <string>Binary</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```